# How edit text/html file via nsI or by another way

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How can i edit text/html file by firefox sdk? I try to use nsI but can't  1)How do that by nsI 2)Is there another way 3) How can i navigate in DOW of html file  for add new tags or delete selected tags in html file.

Comment: Is this a file on the filesystem? What is NSL?

Comment: 1)File in data folder of addon. 2)Sorry, i mean nsIFile or nsILocalFile

Answer (score 0):

Use OS.File - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread

As a second option, since you are using the SDK, you can consider using io/file module - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/io_file

Comment: OK. From which location method **read** will read the **fileTest.txt**?  `let decoder = new TextDecoder();        
 let promise = OS.File.read("fileTest.txt");`                                                                       What I need? For example tag <img> can load image from data directory of addon use scheme **resource:** like :  `<img src="resource://myfirefox-addon/data/dataTest/Averenges.jpg" />`. I need the similar simple! I want to read from/write to(not overwrite) text file inside my firefox addon  use that simple access via **resource:** scheme? Is that possible?